# Data Recovery from unidentified disk

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I was having windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 on dual boot. Somehow my windows 8 was crashed so i reinstalled windows but now i'm not able to access ubuntu as well the data on it.I checked disk management in windows, it shows the partition in which ubuntu was installed as primary partition but shows as 100% free and also does not show any drive name. So I have lost my all important files.Can anybody help me in recovering those files...???

Answer (score 0):

Peoblem is that `windows` can not read `ubuntu/linux` partitions.

Tray to recover boot link is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

After recovery you will be able to boot into `ubuntu`.